# Java get for two different method

Tags: java, class, methods

Can anyone help, how to correctly implement next task: I have two different method in class and one get() to return result on this method. For example:

```java
public class MyClass {
    
    private String Data1;
    private String Data2;
    
    public void Method1() {
        this.Data1 = "111";
    }
    
    public void Method2() {
        this.Data1 = "222";
    }
    
}
```

then I call

```
new MyClass ().Method1().get() //Expect to get 111
new MyClass ().Method2().get() //Expect to get 222
```

and how to create this get method? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you read it again, yourself? `Method1` and `Method2` return `void`.. you can't invoke anything on `void`.. and furthermore - you don't seem to have `get()` defined anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
        myclass.Method1();
        myclass.Method2();

    }
    
    private String Data1;
    private String Data2;

    public void Method1()
    {
        this.Data1 = "111";
        System.out.println(Data1);
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        this.Data2 = "222";
        System.out.println(Data2);
    }


}
```

Initialize the class object as `MyClass myclass = new MyClass();`
The call the methods

```
myclass.Method1();
myclass.Method2();
```

Read more about this keyword using the official Java Docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you want to implement but the closest thing in java following the POO pattern would be something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Sub obj_sub = new Sub();
        System.out.println("value of Data1: " + obj_sub.getData1());
        System.out.println("value of Data2: " + obj_sub.getData1());
    }

    public static class Sub {
        private String Data1, Data2;
        public Sub() {
            super();
            setData1("111");
            setData2("222");
        }
        public String getData1() {
            return Data1;
        }
        public void setData1(String data1) {
            Data1 = data1;
        }
        public String getData2() {
            return Data2;
        }
        public void setData2(String data2) {
            Data2 = data2;
        }
    }
}
```